# What is the proper way to use 初回?

Tags: word-requests, wago-and-kango

How would you say, I saw that movie for the first time? Would you use 初回 or a different word like 
第一回? What are the differences between using these words to describe the "first time" doing something if there are any?

Comment: Provide us with an initial attempt at translation so that we can revise and recommend as is necessary.

Answer (score 4):

An adverb 初めて means "for the first time", and you should be using this in most situations. See [this page](http://[this%20page](https://ejje.weblio.jp/sentence/content/%E5%88%9D%E3%82%81%E3%81%A6)%20for%20the) for examples.

初回 is a relatively uncommon kango noun (see [Sino-Japanese vocabulary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sino-Japanese_vocabulary) and [wago-and-kango](/questions/tagged/wago-and-kango)). It's a stiff word used mainly in serious business articles or in technical/academic contexts. If you don't know how to use 初めて (JLPT N5 word), you may revisit 初回 after you have reached the N3 level. 第n回 is a way to count events that are held regularly (e.g. 第25回XYZコンテスト = "The 25th XYZ Contest").

Answer (score 0):

I saw that movie for the first time.
私はあの映画を初めてみた。
for the first time = 初めて

Would you use 初回 or a different word like 第一回? 
No. 
初回 and 第一回 means “the first time” ,Noun.